# Capistrano error during deploy setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm new to Rails and Capistrano. I'm trying to get a Rails app setup on our demo server and I'm being met with an error during cap deploy:setup. 
The error is:
gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:105:in `on': please specify only a task name or a block, but not both (ArgumentError)

I'm not sure where to look to fix this.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the deploy/demo.rb

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server 'db.example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{db}

server 'demo1.demo.com', user: 'demo-admin', roles: %w{web app db}


# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any  hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}

role :app, %w{demo-admin@demo1.demo.com}
role :web, %w{demo-admin@demo1.demo.com}
role :db,  %w{demo-admin@demo1.demo.com}



# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.

set :rails_env, 'demo'
set :migrate_env, 'demo'
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.1@evcc'
set :passenger_rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.1'

#set :branch, 'develop'



# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server 'example.com',
#   user: 'user_name',
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user_name', # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: 'please use keys'
#   }
```

Here is the deploy.rb

```
#config valid only for current version of Capistrano
#lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:foo/my_app.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/sites/my_app'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
#set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
#set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'app/views/layouts/newsletters')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

set :migrate_target, :latest

# Restart using 'passenger-config restart-app'
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, false

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Is that the only error you have? Could you post your config/deploy/demo.rb

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee, I added the 2 deploy files. Thanks.

Comment: In your files I cannot spot any errors. This error is raised if you use one of the following `on :after, ...` or `on :before ...`. Check if one of your files has this code with `grep -rnP "on :before|on :after" conifg/`

Comment: Thanks @sugaryourcoffee. That's what it was. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as solved, and you get credit? Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is raised if you use one of the following `on :after, ...` or `on :before ....` Check if one of your files has this code with `grep -rnP "on :before|on :after" conifg/`

Comment: Thank you @sugaryourcoffee.